# replacing "\xf3" and "\xe9" with their normal forms

Tags: python, unicode, web-scraping, unicode-normalization

I am scraping data from a website which has some non-english-alphabet letters such as ***Vitória*** which completely mess my data up since the output is ***Vit\xf3ria***.

How do i replace the  \xf3 and others like it?

ps:

```
text.replace('\xf3', '')
```

does not work. And if possible i would love to get the **ó** or such letters displayed and savable in csv format.

Comment: Can you paste here the html elements for one such name?

Comment: Maybe try `text.encode('utf-8')` to convert to bytes?

Comment: @match text.encode('utf-8') changes the outputof Vitória to Vit\xc3\xb3ria

Comment: Those are unicode characters. If you're using Python2 open the file in binary mode, for Python3 set the encoding to 'utf-8'

Comment: @sim html elements is a <span class="Kambi_Wrap_giver">

Comment: @t.m.adam im scraping the data from a site. how do i do that(open the file in binary mode)?

Comment: @Cave Man, you didn't get me. I expected to see how any name is lying within html elements. The portion you have pasted above doesn't contain any name.

Comment: When you open the file to write your csv data, use `open(path, 'wb')` for Python2, or `open(path, encoding='utf-8', mode='w')` for Python3

Comment: @t.m.adam oooh i tried that. it return this error: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Can you include a minimal example of your code and data?

Comment: @t.m.adam done. check below

Comment: Cool! +1 for making the effort to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figured out the answer thanks to all the help in the comments:
credits:
@SIM, @match, @t.m.adam and @dax

here goes.

```
text.encode('utf-8').strip()
```

thanks to all.

**code as is:**

```
...
for cell2n3 in row.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'KambiBC-event-participants__name'}):
    cell2n3append.append(cell2n3.text.encode('utf-8').strip())
...
```

**ps**
in terminal the output is as before...eg.

before(***'Cear\xe1-CE'***) -->now(***'Cear\xc3\xa1-CE'***)

but in csv it is ***Ceará-CE***

Comment: for the love of knowing visit here https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3:

```
>>> bytes('Vit\xf3ria', 'unicode-escape').decode('unicode-escape')
'Vitória'
```

Comment: That's exactly the same as `'Vit\xf3ria'` in the first place, there's absolutely no need to encode and decode with the same codec. Try `'Vit\xf3ria' == 'Vitória'`.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. i'm scraping a lot of changing data and there is no way i can use 'Vit\xf3ria' == 'Vitória' for all of them.... well there is but it will take me days(and i'll probably not get all.) But your way works in python3(true)

Answer (score 0):

**Fix** your encoding errors **as early as possible**, not with a late character replacement.

So rather than fixing encodings of extracted strings, read the correct encoding of the web page early (use http headers, meta Tags, and such) and then all the scraped strings should be correct.